# Sequential Numbers Automatically Populate a field

Tags: sql, function, vba, ms-access

I have an Access database that we use to house Worker's Compensation Accident Information. One of the required fields is an OSHA recordable number that is sequential starting with "01" and the two digit year of the accident (ex. 01-14).

I need to be able to programmitically look into my table see what numbers have already been used and find the next number in the sequence. It also needs to reset to 1 at the beginning of a new year.

Example:
table reads

```
01-14 
02-14
03-14
```

The new number that populates the textbox should be 04-14

Help!

Comment: What is an excel database?

Comment: Excel Spreadsheet, or MS-Access database?

Comment: Do you use `DATE()` to determine the year, or is someone manually entering the year?

Comment: Is this a multi-user database?

Comment: What happens when you have more than 99 accidents?

Comment: This isn't an excel question.  This is a multiuser database and yes I will use the date() or year() function to determine the year. Don't want them to have to type anything in. We have never run into a problem where we have had 99 accidents, knock on wood, but it that happens then the beginning number would turn into a three digit number per OSHA regulations.

Comment: The difficult part in this scenario is evaluating the `PK`. MS Access selects from left to right, so 03-14 is greater than 01-15. What would be needed is to evaluate both parts of the PK, separately, on either side of the `-`. If your PK was 2014-01, 2014-02, 2015-01 then it would be a little bit easier.

Comment: What version of Access are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have a multi-user database, see [insert query with sequential primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517498/insert-query-with-sequential-primary-key/12528222#12528222) or [Access VBA: Find max number in column and add 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949603/access-vba-find-max-number-in-column-and-add-1/11950647#11950647) for code to get the next sequential number.

You can use Year and the seed number to create the next OSHA number. You can reset the seed number on year change.

DMax is a possibility, but I strongly suggest you do not use it in a multi-user database.

Comment: (About `DMax`) why not?

Comment: @Yawar There is a possibility of duplicates, the likelihood increasing with the number of entries and the number of users. By the time you have got the DMax number and saved the record, some other user may also have got the same DMax number. It should not be risked.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described, it sounds like the OSHA number should be generated as and when needed instead of being assigned and stored when the table row is created. My suggestion would be to just have the primary key (`accident_id`) be an autoincremented long integer, the standard practice in Access. And also you need an `accident_date` column to be a `datetime` or similar. Or at the very least an `accident_year` column. Then when you need an OSHA number (say in a report), just have some VBA to generate it using the primary key--`accident_id`--and the `accident_date` or `accident_year` column. You will be taking advantage of the fact that Access autoincremented primary keys are never re-used--even when their rows are deleted, those numbers are never recycled to be used in other rows. So given a long integer primary key, and a date, you can always reproduce the *exact same* OSHA number, with a simple algorithm something like the following:

```
function osha_number(accident_id as long) as string
  accident_year = ... ' get (last two digits of) accident year from accidents table using ID
  year_first_accident_id = ... ' get ID of first accident of this year
  year_this_accident_num = accident_id - year_first_accident_id + 1

  osha_number = year_this_accident_num & "-" & accident_year
end function
```