# Adding a new record to unique ID from UserForm

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to add a new record (unique ID) from a UserForm in Access. I have SQL code to Select the Last ID in the table, but even this did not work. It seemed to just grab the first ID. Is there a way, so that when I click the Combobox on the Userform a new unique Id is generated based on the last table value (without adding that value to the table).

```
SELECT Last(IDNumber) AS Expr1
FROM tbID;
```

Thanks much.

Comment: If this is a multiuser system, that is not a good idea, and even at that, max would be better.

Comment: Is it better to append the (other) values to the table and then let the table auto-generate the new record number?

Comment: Very much so. It is quite complicated to get a new number in a multiuser system.

Comment: Note that auto-generated numbers may not be sequential, merely unique, and even that is arguable.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the feedback. One other question though..if you are creating new unique IDs at "random" are there any obvious ways to know which record is which...how to query them/keep track of your records?

Comment: Check out @identity in this forum.

Comment: Hmm, if you mean how does a user find a record, an auto-number is not the way to go, identity numbers are for the db, not the user.

Comment: Here are some notes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517498/insert-query-with-sequential-primary-key/12528222#12528222

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Last* and *First* really just picks *some* value.

This will more likely succeed (ignoring for a moment the good advice in the comments):

```
SELECT Max(IDNumber) AS Expr1
FROM tbID;
```

Comment: That depends. If the ID is for the vehicles of your company, these are probably not entered massively by the second.

Comment: Famous last words. Design for the future. I have been doing this stuff for quite a while.

Comment: So have I, and learned not to complicate matters beyond reason. Of course, for - say - an audit trail such a simple method won't be reliable.